# Scope_Identity() is returning a blank string

Tags: c#, sql, scope-identity

Below is a section of code with two parts. Almost identical to each other. They both insert something into a table, then call Scope_identity. I've checked to make sure the AddressType is being inserted, and it gives me the CityId just fine. I can't see the difference. I've looked over the code and can't find my mistake. I'm hoping someone can be an extra set of eyes and point out what, I am sure, must be an obvious mistake.

```
SqlCommand addressTypeCommand = new SqlCommand(
       "INSERT INTO AddressType VALUES ('" + customerRow.AddressType + "');",
                    newCustConnection);
try
{
    addressTypeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (SqlException addressTypeException)
{
    if (addressTypeException.ToString().StartsWith(
             "Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unique Key exception on 'AddressType'.");
    }
}

SqlCommand selectAddressTypeID = new SqlCommand(
      "select SCOPE_IDENTITY();", newCustConnection);
string addressTypeID = selectAddressTypeID.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

SqlCommand cityCommand = new SqlCommand(
       "INSERT INTO City VALUES ('" + customerRow.City + "');", 
       newCustConnection);
try
{
    cityCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (SqlException cityException)
{
    if (cityException.ToString().StartsWith(
             "Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unique Key exception on 'City'.");
    }
}
SqlCommand selectCityID = new SqlCommand(
       "select SCOPE_IDENTITY();", newCustConnection);
string cityID = selectCityID.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Comment: What are the table definitions? Do they both have `IDENTITY` columns? Also you should use parameterised queries. And best to have the `;SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` immediately after the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Instead of `if (addressTypeException.ToString().StartsWith("Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint"))` you should check the [`Number`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number(v=vs.110).aspx) property, constraint exception has `2627`. Otherwise your code depends on the localized error message.

Comment: For `scope_identity()` to work it needs to be in the same scope as the insert. From books online, a scope is a "module: a stored procedure, trigger, function, or batch". I'm not sure you've hit any of those.

Comment: @Laurence - It should work until they parameterise it AFAIK. e.g. in an SSMS new query window do `DECLARE @T TABLE(X INT IDENTITY);INSERT INTO @T DEFAULT VALUES;` then execute separately (in the same window) `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` it still has the identity from the previous batch. Once parameterised the query will show up as `sp_executesql` and run in a child batch and then the `SCOPE_IDENTITY` will be lost for the subsequent call.

Comment: @MartinSmith Fair point, though I'm more confused now as to what the problem might be!

Comment: @Laurence - Maybe both tables don't have `IDENTITY` columns. Maybe one of the inserts is encountering an error that is being swallowed by the `catch` (catches `SqlException` but only reports some of them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `scope_identity()` you need to be in the same scope as the insert. The easiest way to achieve this is to pass it as part of the same batch.

e.g.

```
SqlCommand addressTypeCommand = new SqlCommand(
   "insert into AddressType values (@addressType); select scope_identity()"
);

addressTypeCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
    // replace with correct datatype, possibly set data length
    "@addressType", SqlDbType.VarChar, customerRow.AddressType
);
addressTypeID = addressTypeCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```